# How to control Python environment activation in a DevContainer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-poetry, vscode-devcontainer

I am mounting the local file system to the container. I noticed that when opening a Terminal in a DevContainer mode, if there is a `.venv` directory in the default directory of the container, that environment gets activated. This is not desired due to two reasons:

- This directory may be mapped from my local file system and cannot be reused in the container.
- The current activation method is unknown and another environment activation method is preferred.

Regarding the second point, I see the command prompt beginning with `(.venv)`, whereas poetry-activated environment must have a different prompt.

I am using poetry as a package manager. The best way to activate the environment is using `poetry shell`. Can I configure VSCode to:

- Stop activating the environment in .venv (at least)?
- Use custom activation technique such as running `poetry shell`?